# change values in a list based on its existing values

Tags: python, list, replace, expression

I have a list that has the data types of a dataframe. I would like to change the values in the list based on the existing values.

```
list = [dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')]
```

I want a new list whose values are "Double" for values "dtype('float64')" and "Long" for anything else. I tried this expression but doesn't work.

```
listnew = ["Double" if x == "dtype('float64')" else "Long" for x in list]
```

Comment: .... why do you think `dtype('int64') == "dtype('float64')"` will *ever* be `True`? One is a `dtype` object, the other is a `str` object.... it will *always be `False`*

Comment: the expression is only true for dtype('float64'), its changed to "Double". If its not true its changed to "Long". Maybe I dont know how this expression works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

list_ = [np.dtype(np.int64) for n in range(18)] + [np.dtype(np.float64) for n in range(6)]

listnew = ["Double" if np.dtype(x) == np.dtype(np.float64) else "Long" for x in list_]

print(listnew)
```

Where

```
list_ = [np.dtype(np.int64) for n in range(18)] + [np.dtype(np.float64) for n in range(6)]
```

is equivalent to your given list:

```
list_ = [np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   np.dtype(np.int64),   \
         np.dtype(np.float64), np.dtype(np.float64), np.dtype(np.float64), \
         np.dtype(np.float64), np.dtype(np.float64), np.dtype(np.float64)]
```

And the output when printing `listnew` is the following list:

```
['Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Long', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double']
```

Comment: That worked. But I can't still understand how it worked and how my code didnt.

Comment: whats the difference between list_[0] and np.dtype(list_[0]). Could you help me with that??

Comment: @pnkjmndhl because your code compares dtypes with strings, and those will **never be equal**